# How to store Stata estimation results to a csv file

Tags: csv, statistics, stata

I use `esttab` (from the `estout` module in SSC) which is nice for formatting results tables from several models.

```
eststo clear
sysuse auto
eststo: quietly regress price weight mpg
eststo: quietly regress price weight mpg foreign
esttab, ar2 csv plain, using results.csv
```

`esttab` can store estimation results to a csv file, but they are clumsy to reuse.

```
|          |est1      |est2      |
|:---------|:---------|:---------|
|          |b/t       |b/t       |
|weight    |1.746559  |3.464706  |
|          |2.723238  |5.493003  |
|mpg       |-49.51222 |21.8536   |
|          |-.5746808 |.2944391  |
|foreign   |          |3673.06   |
|          |          |5.370142  |
|_cons     |1946.069  |-5853.696 |
|          |.541018   |-1.733408 |
|N         |74        |74        |
|adj. R-sq |.2734846  |.4781119  |
```

I would like to access the model variables and their individual coefficients to display a selection of them in a table. Rather than having an already formatted table, I would prefer a long list in the format below:

```
|estimation |variable |coefficient |t-value   | 
|:----------|:--------|:-----------|:---------|
|est1       |weight   |1.746559    |2.723238  |
|est1       |mpg      |-49.51222   |-.5746808 |
etc...
|est1       |N        |74          |          |
|est1       |adj.R-sq |.2734846    |          |
|est2       |weight    |3.464706   |5.493003  |
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `wide` option?

```
eststo clear
sysuse auto, clear

eststo: quietly regress price weight mpg
eststo: quietly regress price weight mpg foreign

// original
esttab, ar2

// wide option
esttab, ar2 wide
```

I guess much of it boils down to what you mean by "clumsy to reuse".

Comment: Thanks, I didn' tknow about wide. By "clumsy to reuse", I mean to reuse in another software. I run 6 models for 12 different datasets. I export my estimation results to csv files for later reuse. Then I would like to access the model variable and their individual coefficients to display a selection of them in a table. Rather than having an already formated table, I would prefer a list with `|estimation |variable |coefficient |t-value   | `

Comment: See also `help statsby` and `help postfile`, which I think should better meet your needs.

Comment: After creating the dataset of results, you can export it using `outfile`.